# cakephp 2 controller not loading "index" default action

Tags: cakephp, controller, cakephp-2.0, url-routing

I recently start having this weird problem, when trying to access this url:
    `http://localhost/xinglong/reservations`
the server doesn't load the page, it just hangs and looks like it is trying to load something.
but when i use this url:
`http://localhost/xinglong/reservations/`
(note the last /) it works fine loading the index action which is the default.

Any ideas for this weird behavior?
Thanks!

Comment: Use htaccess rule to add trailing slash in your url.

Comment: Also, have a look at the [DirectorySlash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) setting, but note the possible security issue if `indexes` is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Check your /app/Config/routes.php

This would be your localhost/

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'items', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Then, you can define it by:

```
Router::connect('/xinglong/reservations', array( 'controller' => 'xinglong', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Or even better:

```
Router::connect('/xinglong/:action/*', array( 'controller' => 'xinglong'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i haven't touched routes.php default setting so I don't believe it was the cause.

Answer (score 0):

using 127.0.0.1 instead of "localhost" solved the issue.
Also configuring Virtual Host in Apache solved the issue and allowed to use "localhost" normally again.